# Why are we working in domains in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble understanding why we usually work in domains in complex analysis?

Domain definition: Open set with every staircase-line is contained with the set.
Why do we need staircase-lines to be contained within an open set? Why is it an useful property.

Comment: What is a staircase-line? If you mean what I think you mean, we want the set to be (arcwise) connected.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic or holomorphic (or meromorphic) on a connected open $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is fully determined by its value on any small disk $D \subset U$ (and even by its value on any sequence with an accumulation point in $U$).

Comment: *Who* defines domain like that?